# Selenium: How to use x and y coordinate position

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using the Selenium method `mouseMoveAt(java.lang.String locator,java.lang.String coordString)`, which requires a `coordString`.

For example : `coordString - x,y position (10,20)`. If I use `10` for `x` and `20` for `y` coordinate, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

`mouseMoveAt(E,(x,y))`

This means you simulate the mouse moving to a specific (x,y) location relative to the top-left corner of element E, independent of where the element lies on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the org.openqa.selenium.Point class and getLocation() method of the WebElement class.

Point getLocation()
Where on the page is the top left-hand corner of the rendered element?
Returns:
A point, containing the location of the top left-hand corner of the element